# Why does this test always hang when run, but always works in Debug?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console, xunit, io-redirection

Why does the following test hang indefinitely when I run it, but when I debug it, it works perfectly?

```
[Fact]
public async Task WhyDoesThis_Test_AlwaysHang()
{
    var foo = Console.IsInputRedirected ? await Console.In.ReadToEndAsync() : string.Empty;
    foo.Should().BeEmpty();
}
```

The actual test executes a library method, but I simplified it for the question as both behave similarly. I am using Rider's default test runner and .NET 8.

The console input is clearly not redirected, so I would expect the test to work without issue, or at least hang in both debug and run modes.

Comment: Probably a classic async deadlock. You have a `.Wait` or `.Result` somewhere

Comment: Works fine on VS and terminal. Likely something to do with Rider's test runner.